# Symfony: Webhook End Point Problems

Tags: symfony, webhooks, endpoint

I am having trouble with Webhook Endpoints.

```
#[Route("/web_hook", name: 'web_hook')]
    public function webhook(Request $request)
    {
        
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        if ($data === null){
            throw new \Exception('bad bad');
        }

        $txt = 'samle of some text text text';
        $myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fwrite($myfile, $data->id);
        fclose($myfile);
        
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        return $response;
    }
```

I am having 0 luck getting it to work, I am sending a POST request to it VIA Postman and it keeps coming back with error 500.

When I visit then URL it gives me this error

"Cannot autowire argument $request of "App\Controller\WebHookController::webhook()": it references class "Symfony\Component\HTTPFoundation\Request" but no such service exists.
"

I based this method off of

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/stripe-level2/webhook-endpoint-setup.

any ideas on what im doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get error message like this

```
Cannot autowire argument $request of
"App\Controller\WebHookController::webhook()": it references class
"Symfony\Component\HTTPFoundation\Request" but no such service exists.
```

mean this service is not available. please try install http-foundation component first.

```
composer require symfony/http-foundation
```

and try to change `use Symfony\Component\HTTPFoundation\Request` to `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`

Comment: Cannot resolve argument $request of "App\Controller\WebHookController::webhook()": Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\WebHookController::webhook()": the $request argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "Symfony\Component\HTTPFoundation\Request".

is what it says now... Weird I thought I had http-foundations installed

Comment: Seem like `Symfony\Component\HTTPFoundation\Request` is not valid location. try change to `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`. In controller file below namespace, above class part